# Web Server tomcat is not loading the ie related css

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an issue with css.
I have a css file which has ie specific css clauses..Like 
.ie7 #div
.ie #table

These css is working good in my local on tomcat server.
But the same css is not loading in IE in my dev system which is also running on tomcat.
When I debug the ie is not recognizing the ie specific css clauses. Also I found out that
the IE is not recognizing even the section and header tags.

Please let me know what can be the work around.
Thanks for your time and help.

Regards,
Varma

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running IE9..

Make sure you don't have [Compatibility Mode turned on](http://www.microsoft.com/library/media/1033/windows/images/internet-explorer/beta/default/ie8_compatibility.jpg), and make sure you have a valid doctype as the very first line to trigger Standards Mode:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

If it *still* doesn't work, then add this meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Concerning this point:

> Also I found out that the IE is not recognizing even the section and
>   header tags.

In older versions of IE, you need this to make the HTML5 semantic tags work properly:

http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I am using IE7. I am testing both the URLs (localhost and dev) in the same browser and in the localhost its working good but not in dev. When I debug through developer tools, i found that the ie specific css is not loading in dev.. but the same css is loading in localhost url with in the same browser.

Comment: Can you paste the HTML that loads the CSS? Edit: No, the meta tag goes in the `<head>` section of your HTML.